# disabling or refusing to accept cookies in moodle

Tags: cookies, moodle

I'm having trouble working with moodle. I've installed it successfully. After I filled the installation form
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.", the second pic. I tried again but it says the same thing for 2 days now. I've tried removing cookies, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way.

In the file

> \moodle\admin\index.php

search and commandout

```
//redirect("index.php?sessionstarted=1&lang=$CFG->lang");
```

This trick worked for me.